# отсортирвать трехмерный массив по сумме массивов

Tags: php

Задача:
есть массив трехмерный:

```
  for($i=0; $i < 30; $i++){
        for($j=0; $j < 20; $j++){
            for($k=0; $k < 10; $k++){
                $threeArr[$i][$j][$k] = rand(1,15);
            }
        }
    }
```

Отсортировать массивы третьего уровня в массиве в порядке убывания значений сумм вложенных в них массивов. 
как можно отсортирвать?

Comment: Покажите, что вы хотите получить на примере. Так как в настоящее время не совсем понятно

Answer (score 0):

Нужно так?

```
 for($i=0; $i < 30; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j < 20; $j++){
        for($k=0; $k < 10; $k++){
            $threeArr[$i][$j][$k] = rand(1,15);
        }
        $summ=array_sum($threeArr[$i][$j]);
        $threeArr[$i][$j]['summ']=$summ;                
    }
    usort($threeArr[$i], function($a,$b){return ($a['summ']-$b['summ']);});
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($threeArr);
```

Comment: да, то что нужнос спасибо!